# How to use generated QrCode in FPDF without storing it

Tags: php, qr-code, fpdf

I'm using the QRCode library from [Simple QR Code](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode) and combined it with the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) library

Here's my controller :

```
$this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$this->fpdf->Cell(80 ,5,'This Is Header',0,0);
$this->fpdf->Cell(80 ,5,QrCode::generate('this is should generate QR'),1,1);
$this->fpdf->Cell(30 ,5,$title,0,1, 'R');
$this->fpdf->Cell(190 ,2,'',0,1);
```

Instead of getting the QR COde rendered, i got xml code like this :

```
<?xml version="1
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><
height="100" fill="#ffffff"
transform="translate(0,0)"><path fill-rule="eve
3L9 3L9 4L10 4L10 5L11 5L11 4L12 4L12 7L11 7L
6L8 8L4 8L4 10L1 10L1 9L3 9L3 8L0 8L0 10L1
13L8 13L8 17L9 17L9 18L8 18L8 21L9 21L9 19L11 1
17L12 16L13 16L13 17L14 17L14 18L16 18L1
16L17 16L17 15L18 15L18 13L17 13L17 12L1
```

I know i can store the .png file of the generated QR like this :

```
$this->fpdf->Cell(20 , 20, $pdf->Image(base_url($data['qr_path']), $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 20), 1,1);
```

But what i want is to render the QR without storing it, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: @KJ how to wrap it to HTML ? i tried to use WriteHTML() but it seems didn't work

Comment: The purpose of the `Cell` method is to write _text_ - so even if you wrapped anything in HTML, that would still _show_ as text, and not get rendered. And the `Image` method wants a path or URL to an image. _Maybe_ it can work with Data URIs, you'd have to test it.

Comment: @KJ , already use your seggestion, and i'd be ok with it, 
Store the qr and delete after render

Comment: Don't call `Image()` inside `Cell()`, it makes no sense. `Cell()` expects a string as 3rd parameter.

Comment: You can use this [QR code library](https://prgm.spipu.net/view/27). It has a `displayFPDF()` method to output the barcode directly in the PDF (in vector format).